# Differences between PHP concurrency model and Node.js concurrency model

Tags: php, node.js, concurrency

I know that node.js is faster than PHP in many operations, like in handling a chat server, but I can't find anywhere the differences between the PHP concurrency model and the one of Node.js.

I know that Node.js works on non blocking I/O async operations, but how does PHP work?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot compare an application server (Node.js) with a programming language (PHP)...

Comment: I'm talking about applications written in PHP and ran by servers like Apache and applicatiosn writtein in Javascript and ran by Node.js

Comment: Then edit your question...

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a programming language. How a server might handle requests for an application written in PHP depends on the server itself. You have many different models:

1. Apache with fCGI has a synchronous (blocking) request-response cycle, spawning instances and using threads as needed.
2. NGINX with fCGI has an event driven, non-blocking I/O model similar to Node.js, except that a PHP interpreter is invoked via fCGI.
3. ReactPHP has an event-driven, non-blocking I/O model, much like Node.js, but for PHP.